# How to obtain AWS username (not full ARN) in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, terraform

If I have credentials that give me the following …

```
$ aws iam get-user
{
    "User": {
        "UserName": "fred-bob",
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2017-04-01T12:34:56Z",
        "UserId": "ABCD1234...",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/fred-bob"
    }
}
```

… is there a Terraform variable that would give me just `"fred-bob"` and not the full ARN?

Comment: Are you interested in getting the name of a user that you've created with Terraform, or the name of the user that is _running_ Terraform?

Comment: If it's the user terraform is running as, it's duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310893/getting-iam-username-in-terraform

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [iam_user](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user.html) resource and access the IAM user's name via the [name](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user.html#name-1) attribute.

You could trivially import your existing "fred-bob" user and observe that the name "fred-bob" is stored in the name:

**Import:**

```
terraform import aws_iam_user.myuser fred-bob
```

**Usage:**

```
"${aws_iam_user.myuser.name}"
```

The resulting tfstate would look something like this (snippet), with "fred-bob" available as the name attribute:

```
"aws_iam_user.myuser": {
    "type": "aws_iam_user",
    "depends_on": [],
    "primary": {
        "id": "fred-bob",
        "attributes": {
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::AWSACCOUNTNUMBER:user/fred-bob",
            "id": "fred-bob",
            "name": "fred-bob",
            "path": "/",
            "unique_id": "UNIQUEID"
        },
        "meta": {},
        "tainted": false
    },
    "deposed": [],
    "provider": "aws"
}
```